# Averaging linear separators obtained from SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

For research purposes, I find myself needing to traing SVM via SGD on a large DS (that is, a large number of examples). This makes using scikit-learn's implementation (`SGDClassifier`) problematic, as it requires loading the entire DS at once.

The algorithm I am familiar with uses n step of SGD to obtain n different separators `w_i`, and then averages them (specifics can be seen in slide 12 of https://www.cse.huji.ac.il/~shais/Lectures2014/lecture8.pdf).

This made me think that maybe I can use scikit-learn to train multiple such classifiers and then take the average of the resulting linear separators (assume no bias).

Is this a reasonable line of thinking, or does scikit-learn's implementation not fall under my logic?

Edit: I am well aware of the alternatives for training SVM in different ways, but this is for a specific research purpose. I would just like to know if this line of thinking is possible with scikit-learn's implementation, or if you are aware of an alternative that will allow me to train SVM using SGD without loading an entire DS to memory.

Comment: So *loading the entire DS at once* is your current issue? Have you tried on a small sample of the entire DS to see if the result look reasonable to you?

Comment: It's not for performance purposes but for research, and I do need to be able to use the entire DS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SGDClassifier` have a `partial_fit` method, and one of the primary objectives of `partial_fit` method is to scale sklearn models to large-scale datasets. Using this, you can load a part of the dataset into RAM, feed it to SGD, and keep repeating this unless full dataset is used.

In code below, I use `KFold` mainly to imitate loading chunk of dataset.

```
class GD_SVM(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sgd = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge',random_state=42,fit_intercept=True,l1_ratio=0,tol=.001)

    def fit(self,X,y):
        cv = KFold(n_splits=10,random_state=42,shuffle=True)
        for _,test_id in cv.split(X,y):
            xt,yt = X[test_id],y[test_id]
            self.sgd = self.sgd.partial_fit(xt,yt,classes=np.unique(y))

    def predict(self,X):
        return self.sgd.predict(X)
```

To test this against regular (linear) SVM:

```
X,y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)   #For simplicity, Pipeline is better choice
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,n_repeats=5,random_state=43)
sgd = GD_SVM()
svm = LinearSVC(loss='hinge',max_iter=1,random_state=42,
                C=1.0,fit_intercept=True,tol=.001)
r = cross_val_score(sgd,X,y,cv=cv)    #cross_val_score(svm,X,y,cv=cv)
print(r.mean())
```

This returned 95% accuracy for above `GD_SVM`, and 96% for `SVM`. In Digits dataset `SVM` had 93% accuracy, while `GD_SVM` had 91%. While these performances are broadly similar, as  these measurements show, please note that they are not identical. This is expected, since these algorithms use [pretty different optimization algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022399/4553309), but I think careful tuning of hyper-parameter would reduce the gap.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the concern of loading all of the data in memory, if you have access to more compute resources, you may want to use PySpark's SVM implementation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-support-vector-machine, as that Spark is built for large scale data processing. I don't know if averaging the separators from multiple Scikit-Learn models would work as expected; there isn't a clean way to instantiate a new model with new separators, based on the documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html), so it would probably have to be implemented as an ensemble approach.

Comment: This implementation does not use SGD, which is unfortunately a requirement for me. Also, it is not hard to change the linear separator of sklearn's SVM object:
`svm_classifier.coef_ = new_vec`

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the whole DS for training instead of sampling (btw that is what the slides describe) and you do not care about performance, I would train `n` classifiers, and then select only their support vectors and retrain final version on those support vectors only. This way you effectively dismiss most of the data and concentrate only on the points that are important for the classification.